# What is the difference between a cover and a subset?

Tags: general-topology

According to Wikipedia,

A set $A$ is a *subset* of a set $B$ if A is "contained" inside $B$, that is, all elements of $A$ are also elements of $B$.

A *cover* $C$ of a set $X$ is a collection of sets whose union contains $X$ as a subset.

What's the difference? Isn't this just saying that a cover is a superset (which is the same as saying $X$ is a subset)?

Comment: you are thus asking what is the difference between a set containing $X$ and a *collection* of sets that *together* (i.e., their union) contain $X$. Well, clearly, every set containing $X$ is also a cover of $X$, but not vise versa. E.g., $\{x\}_{x\in X}$ is a cover of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

No,  $X$ doesn't have to be a subset of $C$.  Here's an example.   Let $X=\{1,2\}$
Then a cover of $X$ is $C=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.   Note that $X$ is NOT a subset of $C$, but is a subset of the union of all the elements of $C$ (In this case, it's equal)